# How to display multiple items types in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, mysql, android-room

I am creating an android app in java, I am using Room database. 
I have three tables :

```
Users table( user_id and user_name) 
Products table( product_id and product_name)
Orders table ( order_id  , user_id  and product_id )
```

I am using ViewModel to query information and populate it to UI.

I have one query that get from Orders table the `user_id`  and `product_id`. 
I have this case : 
user_id number 1 have ordered 3 products.

```
private void setUpViewModel() {

viewModel.getUserProduct(1).observe(this,new Observer<List<OrdersTable>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<OrdersTable> order) {
                mAdapter.setUserList((ArrayList<OrdersTable>) order);
            }
        }
       );
     }
```

this query will get product 1,2 and 3 for user No.1

I want to display the user name and product name in my `recylcerView` but i do not know how to display two different type of table ( User table and product table) in the `recylcerView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/tv_userName_xml"
    android:text="user name"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_prodcutName_xml"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:text="product"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

```
 public class MyAdapter extends   RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
 private Context mContext;
 ArrayList<OrderTable> order_list;
 ArrayList<UserTable> user_list; 
 ArrayList<ProductTable> product_list;

 public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

 @NonNull
@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_ts,  parent, false);
    MyAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder = new   MyAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    OrderTable orders = order_list.get(position);
    UserTable user = user_list.get(position);
    ProductTable productTable = product_list.get(position);

    holder.tv_userName.setText(user.getUserName());

    holder.tv_productName.setText(productTable.getProductName());
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (order_list == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return order_list.size();
  }


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_userName, tv_productName;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_userName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_userName_xml);
        tv_productName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_prodcutName_xml);

    }

}

public void setTs_list(ArrayList<OrderTable> ts) {
    this.order_list = ts;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


 }
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear of what you want.

Comment: Can you explain this `   UserTable user = order_list.get(position);
    ProductTable productTable = order_list.get(position);`You are getting UserTable, ProductTable from list which holds only OrderTables

Comment: I want from the recyclerView to display two type of objects ( UserTable Object and ProductTable Object) Sorry i did not declare the variable  ArrayList<UserTable> user_list; ArrayList<ProductTable> product_list;  it should be          UserTable user = user_list.get(position);     PoductTable productTable = product_list.get(position);

Comment: Do you want to show multiple product names in a single `TextView` named `tv_productName`?

Comment: Can you confirm that you only want to display info from 2 diffrent lists, but in same recyclerview item?

Comment: sorry for my unclear question :( ,  i want to display two diffrent type of lists ArrayList<UserTable>  user_list;  ArrayList<ProductTable> product_list; in same recyclerview

Comment: show us your xml file for recyclerview item

Comment: Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the data from these tables and bind that result in a custom model  class called `ResultModel` You can get `user_name` and `product_name` from that `ResultModel`

**user** table

[image]

**product** table

[image]

**t_order** table

[image]

Join query :

> select u.user_name, p.product_name from user u, product p, t_order o
>   where o.user_id = u.user_id  and o.product_id = p.product_id

**result**

[image]

Create one model class `ResultModel`

```
public class ResultModel {
  public String getUser_name() {
   return user_name;
  }

  public String getProduct_name() {
   return product_name;
  }

  private String user_name;
  private String product_name;
}
```

**Updated observer**

Note: replace `OrdersTable` with `ResultModel` wherever required in your `Adapter` too

```
viewModel.getUserProduct(1).observe(this,new Observer<List<ResultModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<ResultModel> order) {
            mAdapter.setUserList((ArrayList<ResultModel>) order);
        }
    }
   );
 }
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Query("select u.user_name, p.product_name from user u, product p, t_order o where o.user_id = u.user_id and o.product_id = p.product_id")                                               LiveData<List<??? >> setUserList();                                                                                    what type of object should be pass in the List ?

Comment: it will be `ResultModel`

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple recycle view inside onBindViewHolder like this

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, int i) {

        final String sectionName = dataList.get(i).getHeaderTitle();

        ArrayList singleSectionItems = dataList.get(i).getAllItemsInSection();

        itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(sectionName);

        SectionListDataAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new SectionListDataAdapter(mContext, singleSectionItems);

        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);

    }



public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView itemTitle;

        protected RecyclerView recycler_view_list;




        public ItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.itemTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            this.recycler_view_list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);


        }

    }
```

[See sample code here](https://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html)

Answer (score -1):

My advice is to use different view types. [Here is an article about it](https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example)

First of all, you have to come up with an abstraction of a data source for your adapter. Usually we have a simple array or a list as a data source, but in your case you have not one but three types. So you can create an interface or use a collection to store all your data inside adapter, the way how you'd like to make it is up to you.
After that, you have to create different constants for each type of your models. In your example you have three models: User, Product and Order. So I'd recommend creating three constants for each of these types. These constants should be placed inside your adapter class as static fields.

```
private static final int USER_VIEW_TYPE = 1;
private static final int PRODUCT_VIEW_TYPE = 2;
private static final int ORDER_VIEW_TYPE = 3;
```

Then, you have to override method `getItemViewType(int position)` in your adapter. There you must tell adapter what type a particular item has. For instance, you've decided to store all your data as `List<Object>` (but don't do that in the production code, I'm using the `Object` type here just for example.). So in this case your method would look like this:

```
@Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (data[position] instanceof User) {
        return USER_VIEW_TYPE;
    } else if (data[position] instanceof PRODUCT_VIEW_TYPE) {
        return PRODUCT_VIEW_TYPE;
    } else return ORDER_VIEW_TYPE;
}
```

After that you need to create different ViewHolders for your types, so you will have a `UserViewHolder`, a `ProductViewHolder` and a `OrderViewHolder`. 
And, in order to differentiate them finally, you should use the `viewType` parameter in the `onCreateViewHolder` method. The logic is quite simple: you have to check value of this parameter and inflate different layouts depending on the result. For example:

```
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        if (viewType == USER_VIEW_TYPE) {
            return new UserViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_user_type, parent));
        } else if (viewType == PRODUCT_VIEW_TYPE) {
            return new ProductViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_product_type, parent));
        } else return new OrderViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_order_type, parent));
    }
```

Comment: He wants multiple products per user, In that case, your suggestion won't work.

Comment: In your onCreateViewHolder there are three layouts , layout.item_user_type, layout.item_user_type and item_order_type.  I have only one layout

Comment: So you want to have a single item where user name and all his products are placed, don't you? If yes, then you have two options: have a recyclerview inside each of your items or have a container and add items dynamically. The first option is a bit harder to implement, but much less error-prone and easier to maintain.